# "crepitation" when viewing videos on facebook with Firefox

Tags: firefox, pulseaudio

Problem only occurs when I try to view videos on my facebook wall in Firefox. There is no sound for the video, only a very loud "crepitation". Using Ubuntu 14.

I already tired to reinstall pulseaudio, didn't helped. I tried to clear the cache/cookies/history in Firefox, didn't helped. I tried to reboot the notebook, didn't help.

**Question**: how can I fix this? Or the solution is to clean install a fresh Ubuntu 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search google for

```
static noise facebook firefox
```

and you can find that facebook made a new proprietary video serving method, that is only supported in Ubuntu 15 (at least it works on it)